# I want to change the Calendar "add" new event on a overlaid calendar to a different calendar

Tags: calendar, redirect, online

I have three calendar views that overlay onto one calendar so I can change colors based on a column choice.  But the "Add" button that is available on the overlay calendar opens the "New Event" for the overlay calendar, not the source calendar.  Is there a way to change the "Add" button so it re-directs to the source calendar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overlays simply point to "Views" even if they are on the same calendar. Perhaps you could try using one calendar with the 3 views and have the overlays on the 'default' calendar view (4 calendar views in total). You can still use the categories to make the 3 views work with filtering. This way the "add event" button is tied to the same calendar as it is by default. One last trick is to do a reverse filter on the main view so you don't see duplicate entries for the event plus the overlay.

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't know you could overlay a calendar's own views onto itself.  I thought you had to overlay a different calendars views.